# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", currentplaylistID);
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, pos);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, audio_id);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAYLIST_ID, currentplaylistID);

resolver.insert(uri, values);
```

It gives the error on the last line, not sure what I'm doing wrong, the playlist is clearly there as I can see it in my "Playlists" listview

Comment: Please try to debug the code.

Comment: Can we know the Data types for 'pos','audio_id' and 'currentplaylistID'? Make sure none of them have primitive data type as 'long'. If yes, change it to Long.

Comment: int pos
String audio_id
Long currentPlaylistID

I made sure that currentPlaylistID is Long and not long